# Items won't get erased after Player picks it up

Tags: c++, sfml

I've tried to give my Player +5 Coins when he picks up an Item which gets randomly dropped on my window. For some reason when I try to pick it up I get tons of coins (5 coins per second) but the Coin image doesn't disappear.

```
counter = 0;
            for (iter11 = pickUpArray.begin(); iter11 != pickUpArray.end(); iter11++)
            {
                if(Player1.rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(pickUpArray[counter].rect.getGlobalBounds())){

                    if(pickUpArray[counter].isCoin == true){
                        Player1.coins += pickUpArray[counter].coinValue; //Adding coinValue on Player1 coins balance
                        pickUpArray[counter].destroyed == true;
                     }
                }

                counter++;
            }
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Maybe check if the coin you are trying to pick up has been destroyed?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d1rofi is that normal? haha

Comment: What is `pickUpArray[counter].destroyed == true;` ?

Comment: in my pickUpItems.h I have: `bool isCoin = true;
    bool destroyed = false;
    int coinValue = 5;`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it didn't delete by itself after I picked it up was: this '=='.

It should be `pickUpArray[counter].destroyed = true;`